# How can I get the content of an element in js?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the value and content of an option element. So far I have it getting the value using `this.value` as shown below

```
<select name='name' id='name' onchange='someFunction(this.value)'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>CONTENT</option>
     " . $options . "
</select>";
```

Can I pass over the "CONTENT" on the `onchange` event as well at the value?

Something like this maybe...
`onchange='showAccountInfo(this.value, ???)`

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name='name' id='name' onchange='someFunction(this)'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>CONTENT</option>
     " . $options . "
 </select>"
```

```js
 function someFunction(obj)
 {
     var value = obj.value;
     var content = obj.querySelector("option:checked").textContent;
 }
```

That should do it:

I changed the object passed in the `onchange` function. It passes the select object to the function using the keyword `this`. Then we use `value` to select the value and a querySelector that selects the selected option using the selector `option:checked`. This way your code becomes more readable.

However you could store it inside the onchange like this:

```
onchange='showAccountInfo(this.value, this.querySelector("option:checked").textContent)'
```

Personally I wouldn't use (or recommend) the use of inline events.

I would do it like this using `addEventListener`:

```js
     function someFunction(e)
     {
        //this refers to the select element (the owner of the event);
         var value = this.value;
         var content = this.querySelector("option:checked").textContent;
         alert("value: " + value + " content: " + content);
     }

     document.querySelector("#name").addEventListener("change", someFunction, false); //attach an onchange event using the addEventListener method.

//I'm using document.querySelector here to select an element on the page.
```

```html
    <select name='name' id='name' >
        <option selected='selected'  value='1:'>CONTENT 1</option>
        <option value='2:'>CONTENT 2</option>
        <option value='3:'>CONTENT 3</option>
        <option value='4:'>CONTENT 4</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: Keep getting this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'option:selected' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: @BigRabbit, true, thought that was correct, but should be `checked` try it now. The snippet works.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. `checked` worked. Also thanks for the advice I will look into inline events.

Comment: When I try to pass `value` back over to my page it is passing an empty string, but when I use alert the value of `value` is not empty...?`xmlhttp.open("GET","somepage.php?=q"+value, true);`

Comment: I cannot give a good answer to this without seeing the way you've implemented the xmlhttp request.