# JS function passing an empty string back to php, but has a value?

Tags: javascript, php

So I am trying to pass back a couple values to a PHP page like this.

```
function showAccountInfo(obj){

    var value = obj.value;
    var content = obj.querySelector("option:checked").textContent;

    alert("value: " + value + " content: " + content);

    if(obj == ""){
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("facilities").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?=q"+value+"&c="+content, true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    }
}
```

When the alert goes off it shows me the correct values for each variable. However when I pass off that value to getinfo.php and use the variable `value` to complete a query and echo it out to the page it shows me it as empty.

```
$q = ($_GET['q']);

$sql = "SELECT *, account.account_name FROM facility "
 . "INNER JOIN account ON account.account_id = facility.account_id "
 . "WHERE facility.account_id = '".$q."'";

echo $sql;
```

Result: `SELECT *, account.account_name FROM facility INNER JOIN account ON account.account_id = facility.account_id WHERE facility.account_id = ''`

I had everything functioning properly prior my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882330/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-an-element-in-js/28882407#28882407).

Comment: Have you checked the generated URL is what you expect in the Net tab of your developer tools? Is the data in the response correct?

Comment: @Quentin just checked, the URL is giving me the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is incorrectly formatted

Change

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?=q"+value+"&c="+content, true);
                                ^
```

To

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?q="+value+"&c="+content, true);
                                 ^
```

Note change of first `=`

Comment: Yep, that was it..should have noticed that, thank you!